# Magento hide configurable product from catalog and search

Tags: magento, hide, configurable

I wish to use layered navigation to group products by similar colours using a custom attribute such as colour_group

Currently my simple products redirect to configurable product.

Example:I want to display SIMPLE PRODUCT Product A(red) / Product A(blue) but hide the the configurable product from catalog and search.

I looked at some solutions for extending the catalog visibility but could only find solutions for hiding out of stock products.

Anyone have any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Visibility" setting for configurable products to "Not Visible Individually".  They will remain accessible by URL only which is what the simple products redirect to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this but I get a 404 when the configurable is set to not visible individually. The URL doesn't change but the configurable product is loaded.

Comment: Ok worked it out in case anyone needs it. Set the configurable to catalog only and ensured it wasn't set to any categories. This way it's not visible in the catalog or search but the child items are redirecting the configurable. This does affect the layered navigation as not all sizes are showing in layered navigation. So on to the next problem...